Is there anything that would prevent peforming Weil Descent on binary curves of large characteristics?
The ghs attack involve creating an hyperlliptic curve cover for a given binary curve. The reason the attack fails most of the time is the resulting genus grows exponentially relative to the curve’s degree.
We don’t hear about the attack on finite fields of large characteristics since such curves are already secure by being prime. However, I notice a few protocol relies on the discrete logarithm security on curves with 400/500 bits modulus resulting from extension fields of characteristics that are 200/245bits long with strictly prime order. Like determining the discrete logarithm between the Generator’s point of the sextic twist of a bn curve and an other point on that sextic twist.
Since the degree is most of the time equal to 3 or 2, is there anything that would prevent creating suitable hyperelliptic cover for such curves in practice ? If yes, what about curves defined on extension fields that aren’t just prime power like for example a curve defined on $F_p^2 = F_p[x]$ ÷ ($x^2$ + 1) ?

Some attempts have been made to attack such curves via Weil descent, for example https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/575, but they have not been implemented and there is some debate as to the correctness of the analysis.

I do see attack claiping to be implementented on degree 4 curves but with 145 bits characteristics. The researcher is a very famous mathemarician in my country.

@djao the paper seems to be about almost prime curves order but in my case the order is fully prime.

@JyrkiLahtonen the 2 questions are indeed different.

@JyrkiLahtonen The other question was about changing the prime field not on elliptic curve but using elliptic curves. In that case, I’m thinking about solving discrete logarithms Y$^2=X^3$+3÷(x+9) over $F_p^2$ = $F_p$[x] ÷ ($x^2 + 1$).

@user2284570 you are misreading the paper. The reason why the paper assumes a group of almost prime order is because that is the current best practice for elliptic curve cryptography. See for example https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/ladder.html ("curves of prime order or 2*prime order can never be converted to Montgomery curves"). The almost prime order assumption is not a requirement.

@dja Maybe. But even then, the case I care about is only on prime order curves.

@djao I was thinking about https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/020.pdf
